# How to display array of strings on a label in string by string in a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

This code is now in the form1 constructor.

```
if (filesRadar.Length > 0)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < filesRadar.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    label2.Text = dates[i].ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH':'mm");
                                }
                            }
```

I want to display the strings in dates when calling a method or something in the constructor and also in other places like when downloading finished. each time calling a method or enabling timer to display the strings in a loop in specific speed.

Now it's displaying but too fast then in the end displaying the last item only and it's not in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or enabling timer to display the strings in a loop in specific speed.

What's keeping you from doing that?...

Drop the timer on your form and set its `Interval` property to something reasonable. For instance, an interval of 1000 would mean it changes every second. Make sure the Timer is turned on (Enabled).

Now move the `i` variable out to class level and get rid of the `for` loop:

```
private int i = -1;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (filesRadar.Length > 0)
    {
        i++;
        if (i >= filesRadar.Length)
        {
            i = 0;
        }                
        label2.Text = dates[i].ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH':'mm");                
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = ""; // optional?
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this has the potential to FAIL if `filesRadar` and `dates` become "out of sync". It's not clear how these two entities are created and updated. The code assumes that `dates` will always have the same number of entries as `filesRadar`. You could add additional checks in the code to "fix" this. A better design would put all related data into some kind of "record structure" such as a Class or by using a database of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this as a void method and you can call whenever you want to:

```
    public void ReportTime()
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < filesRadar.Length; i++)
                label2.Text += dates[i].ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH':'mm") + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `if-statement`, because the loop will only execute if there are items in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filesRadar.Length; i++)
{
    label2.Text += dates[i].ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH':'mm") + Enviroment.NewLine;
}
```